# "Automatic" GPS clock won't update to correct time - 2007 Honda Odyssey

Tags: honda, odyssey, accessories, gps, infotainment

We have a 2007 Honda Odyssey, equipped with a GPS/map system (it's a touchscreen). According to the quick-start guide, GPS-equipped Odysseys are able to set their own clock based on the time zone that the car is in. Hence, the built-in digital clock has no way to manually adjust it, as do the vans without GPS. The clock (a small LCD next to the touchscreen) worked perfectly for the first 1½ years or so after we bought the car in 2020, automatically adjusting even mid-trip.

But one day a couple months ago, the battery died (a light got left on). We took it out, charged it, and put it back in, entered the PIN to get back into the infotainment system, and since then, the clock has never showed the correct time. We entered the PIN only after several trips, spanned over several days, because we'd lost the number and it took us a while to find it again.

We also found how to set ***a*** clock(?) by looking through the infotainment system settings, but changing that clock doesn't affect the problematic one.

There are several odd things about this problem:

1. The clock is a random number of hours *and minutes* off; for example, when driving at 8:30 AM, it shows 2:18 (that's not a specific example, but an accurate one). This shows that it's not getting time-zones mixed up.
2. It's consistent; the clock is keeping track of the "time", even when the time is incorrect. When we drive to school in the morning, at the same time, the clock always shows the same incorrect time.
3. The GPS itself works perfectly. It accurately displays the location and orientation of the van while we're driving, with all the correct road names, landmarks, etc.

We eventually resorted to Command®-Stripping a wristwatch to the dash.

Does anyone know what is wrong, and if there's an easy (and inexpensive) way to fix this? Could it have to do with the fact that we entered the PIN late? If you need any more information about the car's condition/features, I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

World wide issue due to bad coding of the gps system.  It happened on Jan 1, 2022.  It will reset itself, mostly, on August 17, 2022. All will work again after that date except for the auto DST updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it would be nice if you provided a citation. What are your sources? Where did you get this information?

Comment: @BlueFlameSix here are some sources: https://www.motor1.com/news/558984/honda-navi-date-time-glitch/ and https://didhondafixtheclocks.com/

Comment: @John - From what you wrote, you seem to be mistating the problem. The coding of the head unit is the issue. You make it sound as though the GPS satellite system is at fault ... I can tell you for a fact, that is not the case.

Comment: Mine fixed today. I am so happy it has been driving me nuts.